# How do you verify a download of the Mercurial software?

Tags: mercurial

Is there some way to verify downloads of the mercurial software? The website provides no checksums or signatures, nor does it provide the ability to use https to download the software. Here's [the link](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads) to the page where I downloaded the software from.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Mercurial now lives at https://www.mercurial-scm.org.

Previously:
You need to download the full repository (from http://selenic.com/hg).
Matt Mackall, the author and maintainer signs releases with his pgp key. selenic.com is also a domain he owns and has been using since more than a decade.